# Converting 3.3v logic level to 5v using octal bus transceiver

Tags: raspberry-pi, breadboard, level-shifting, logic-level

I'm using the Raspberry PI to communicate with various sensors and other circuits that input and output 5V logic level. The Raspberry Pi itself has 3.3V GPIOs, so i need to convert the logic levels.

I found the following chip, with this capability:
http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1635559.pdf

I'm quite new to hardware development and would like to know if I have to purchase any other components to use this chip. The datasheet mentions pull-up resistors for instance.

I also found this ready to go chip that I think uses the same component.  I can see various other components on it, but I would like to use the breadboard version :

http://ee.farnell.com/adafruit-industries/395/logic-level-converter-8ch-arm-development/dp/2301650?dimVals=110514096

Can anyone provide me with a circuit to hook up the SN74LVC245AN safely and effectively on a breadboard.

Comment: Do your GPIOs ever change between input and output?

Comment: Also, the breakout uses a completely different chip.

Comment: During operation I don't intend to change GPIO modes from input to output. I use different GPIO pins for input and output. I do however think I need two of these chips, 3.3v to 5v and vice versa.

Comment: The '245A won't help you then, since it won't do 3V3 and 5V output at the same time. Look at the '07 or TXB01nn instead.

Comment: As I understood the  '245A can do conversion both ways (not at the same time.) I can use two of these chips and get the job done. The main problem is that I don't know what kind of circuit to use with the chips.

Comment: The '245A doesn't actually convert; it allows you to input CMOS-level signals referenced *above* Vdd, and outputs CMOS-level signals referenced *to* Vdd. But if Vdd is 5V then there's no way for it to input 3V3 CMOS-level signals, and if Vdd is 3V3 then there's no way for it to output 5V CMOS-level signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sparkfun has two logic level translator boards.  One is $3.95 and the other $6.95.  [The cheaper one is based around the TI TXB0104 chip](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11771), and has 4 bi-directional channels.  I have successfully used this chip in a commercial product where I had to translate back and forth between 3.3v to 1.8v for a cell module.

[image]

I wouldn't think pull-up resistors would be needed unless you are using an I2C bus.
Their site has a nice [hookup guide](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/txb0104-hookup-guide) for this breakout board, including a sample for connecting a device to an Arduino. Note: Just opposite of what you are trying to do, since the Arduino is 5v and the peripheral is 3.3v)